# Highlighted text is not readable in text editor with dark mode on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, themes, gtk, gedit

I have an issue with the text editor on Ubuntu 20.04. With dark mode enabled, the highlighted text is not readable.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?